# Issue with solidity contract deployment

Tags: kubernetes, ethereum, solidity, geth

We have developed/modified a few solidity contracts.
Those are properly deployed in
Local Ganache dev
Rinkeby Testnet

Now we have created an environment with ethereum and Kubernetes.
Where geth is running properly inside the pod, we can check
the accounts and make transactions between accounts.

But when try to deploy our solidity contract to this environment
then it is failing with this error.

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:   Deployment Failed 

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.
```

Please let me know if any further information required.
It will great help if you can share some guidance.
For ethereum and kubernetes we use this
https://github.com/kairen/kubereum

Comment: You do not need to have a Kubernetes or geth to deploy contracts - so there is something missing in the question context

Comment: I am deploying smart contract in private blockchain.

Comment: @SwarupMukherjee What's the genesis of the private chain? Likely it is missing some newer opcodes. It is best to use the pupeth tool to generate a correct genesis.